# Minecraft gives Unexpected exception refreshing version list - socket connection Timeout

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking, minecraft-launcher

Can someone help me fix this glitch for Minecraft?

```
[16:20:19 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
[16:20:19 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.3.9 (through bootstrap 5) started on windows...
[16:20:19 INFO]: Current time is Feb 2, 2014 4:20:19 PM
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_51'
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
[16:20:19 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'
[16:20:19 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
[16:20:34 ERROR]: Unexpected exception refreshing version list
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Http.performGet(Http.java:56) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.RemoteVersionList.getContent(RemoteVersionList.java:26) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionList.refreshVersions(VersionList.java:77) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionManager.refreshVersions(VersionManager.java:60) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:164) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
[16:20:34 INFO]: Loaded 1 profile(s); selected 'alkosh1999'
[16:20:34 INFO]: Refreshing auth...
[16:20:34 INFO]: Logging in with access token
[16:21:10 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version
[16:21:10 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads
[16:21:10 INFO]: Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (16 threads, 27 files)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.1-nightly-20131120\lwjgl_util-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.2\authlib-1.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\5.12\twitch-5.12.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1-nightly-20131120\lwjgl-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:10 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\naw\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[16:21:15 WARN]: Couldn't download https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.5/jopt-simple-4.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.ChecksummedDownloadable.download(ChecksummedDownloadable.java:49) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:108) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
[16:21:15 WARN]: Couldn't download https://libraries.minecraft.net/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.1-nightly-20131120/lwjgl-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
```

Comment: You will need to connect to the Internet properly. I'm guessing you're behind a firewall or router blocking that connection.

Comment: Since all those errors are connection failures, have you set up your firewall correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure why this needs closing. There is a problem, the answer might be obvi if you know where to look (but asker probably doesn't), but it has an answer. If this is about a meta decision, please link the meta in the comment before voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting from a different connection and see if it works. Sounds like you are connecting behind a school/workplace connection, which is blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download minecraft in minecraft.net, it will download the resource files.
2. Open minecraft launcher that you download in minecraft.net and login.
   2a. If you do not have an account, register in minecraft.net.
3. Back to the launcher, go to the bottom left and click the edit profile.
4. check all the box except the version selections.
5. click play.
6. open your minecraft launcher that you need to fix and repeat the above steps. 7. click play when it is done loading. 
   When the play button again is back in the normal color you need to restart your broken MC Launcher.

If all else fails, restart computer.

Comment: Your answer is very unclear due to lack of punctuation.  You can [edit] your answer to fix this.

Comment: "my answer is"
lol irl